# Manipulating Inline Text with JQuery or CSS3 Transitions (or both)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

Over the last two days I've been working on manipulating inline text that sits between `<span>` tags.

For something close to the effect I'm looking for, check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/6uf96/5/

On JSFiddle, in the "Result" box, hover over the yellow "Activate Div".  If you're on Chrome, the pink text rolls up as if it is a [tape measure](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/tape-measure-1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://home.howstuffworks.com/tape-measure.htm&h=267&w=400&sz=53&tbnid=hGlL4eEeSMFnVM%3a&tbnh=91&tbnw=136&zoom=1&usg=__fLI0iTS9h5IAJi7MrMegpkOLhE4=&docid=V-t36e6NxNoLVM&sa=X&ei=HdSyUf-SA6qgigeeoIHYDA&ved=0CEYQ9QEwBA&dur=162) retracting, and the green text rolls out as if it is a tape measure being pulled out.  That kind of sliding "appearing" and "disappearing" is the effect I'm going for.

To achieve this I'm using CSS transitions between letter spacing values (see "deletion" and "insertion" classes).  The pink highlighted text transitions from normal spacing to highly negative spacing (to go from visible to invisible), and the green highlighted text transitions between highly negative spacing to normal spacing (to go from invisible to  visible).

The issue is that this method really trips out the browsers.  It works ok on Chrome (although it's quite jittery and there is sometimes trouble with the unhighlighted text).  It doesn't seem to work on Safaari at all - the pink and green sections just disappear and appear respectively.

I've tried to achieve the effect using `<div>` tags with "overflow" and JQuery's `.animate()` (animating between high width and low width divs and hiding the overflow text that spills out of the low width div).  This works really well until you have text that breaks the line - it doesn't work at all then, so this method seems to be out of the question (unless someone knows something that I don't).

So, the million dollar question: does anyone know of a plugin or another technique to do this kind of inline text manipulation, even across line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

To get it working in Safari you need to use the prefixed version of transtions. Which means you need to add `-webkit-transition` to the regular `transition`.

I updated your jsFiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/6uf96/7/